# Why does time.sleep not complain when passed True?

Tags: python, sleep

So I just tracked down a strange bug in my Python program which was caused by that fact that I mixed up arguments to a function and mistakenly passed `True` to `time.sleep()`.  Python seems to silently convert `True` to `1`

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) say:

> Suspend execution for the given number of seconds. The argument may be
>   a floating point number ...

In general, Python is happy to throw exceptions when input does not match the expected type or range.  Why does `sleep`  silently convert `True` to a number?

Comment: Is `sleep` the only function that does this?  Or do other functions silently convert `True` to a number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python, `Bool` is a subclass of `int`

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

Here's the source from svn: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Modules/timemodule.c

`PyArg_ParseTuple` converts the arg to a `float` with the `d:` specifier

```
static PyObject *
time_sleep(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    double secs;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "d:sleep", &secs))
        return NULL;
    if (floatsleep(secs) != 0)
        return NULL;
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}
```

Comment: `bool` is a subclass of `int` in **all** versions of Python that support `bool`. Unlike Java, Python doesn't shy away from `True` and `False` being numeric values. Any place that accepts integers, and `time.sleep` definitely qualifies, must also accept bools.

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize that was the case for py3k also

Comment: Note that languages that distinguish bools from numbers often do it for practical reasons, such as to make `if (foo = 3)` an error. Python doesn't have this problem since assignments aren't valid expressions anyway.

Comment: `True` acts like the int `1` and `False` like the int `0`; e.g., `float(True)` is `1.0`, `"abc"[True]` is `"b"`, `sleep(True)` sleeps for 1 second.

Comment: This explains it.  I'm just used to Python telling me via exception when I make a gross type error, which was exactly what this was in my case.